# Swift on OS X. How to handle global mouse events?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode7

I am new to Swift and Xcode and I have next problem:

I have simple Cocoa Swift Application with one counter (`Label`). 
[image]

**How to handle all mouse clicks in my Mac (in all applications) and display it in my `Label`?**

I use Xcode 7.3.1.

**UPDATE 1.** What I have already found it's [Monitoring Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html) and `addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:` function in Cocoa, but I'm not sure that I'm on the right way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct about using **[`addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:)**

A simple example might look something like this:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet var textLabel : NSTextField!
    var eventHandler : GlobalEventMonitor?
    var gecount : Int = 0

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

        eventHandler = GlobalEventMonitor(mask: .LeftMouseDownMask, handler: { (mouseEvent: NSEvent?) in
        self.gecount += 1
        self.textLabel.stringValue = "global event monitor: \(self.gecount)"
    })
    eventHandler?.start()
  }
}
```

**GlobalEventMonitor.swift**

```
public class GlobalEventMonitor {

    private var monitor: AnyObject?
    private let mask: NSEventMask
    private let handler: NSEvent? -> ()

    public init(mask: NSEventMask, handler: NSEvent? -> ()) {
        self.mask = mask
        self.handler = handler
    }

    deinit {
        stop()
    }

    public func start() {
        monitor = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(mask, handler: handler)
    }

    public func stop() {
        if monitor != nil {
            NSEvent.removeMonitor(monitor!)
            monitor = nil
        }
    }
}
```

<sub>Events are delivered asynchronously to your app and you can only observe the event; you cannot modify or otherwise prevent the event from being delivered to its original target application. Key-related events may only be monitored if accessibility is enabled or if your application is trusted for accessibility access (see AXIsProcessTrusted).</sub>

> Note that your handler will not be called for events that are sent to
>   your own application.

In order to capture events within your app your can either use the **[`addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:handler:)** or the **[`NSClickGestureRecognizer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsgesturerecognizer)** object.

If you wanted to combine the global event monitor with the gesture recognizer object it's simply a matter of implementing both objects into your class.

Comment: This is unfortunately outdated :(

Answer (score 1):

Updated code of the @l'L'l's version posted above.

**Updated mask:** `.LeftMouseDownMask` -> `.leftMouseDown`

```
        eventHandler = GlobalEventMonitor(mask: .leftMouseDown, handler: {
                   (mouseEvent: NSEvent?) in
            self.gecount += 1
            self.textLabel.stringValue = "global event monitor: \(self.gecount)"
        })
        eventHandler?.start()
```

**Updated a few parts with outdated syntaxt.**

```
import AppKit

public class GlobalEventMonitor {

    private var monitor: AnyObject?
    private let mask: NSEvent.EventTypeMask
    private let handler: (NSEvent?) -> ()

    public init(mask: NSEvent.EventTypeMask, handler: @escaping (NSEvent?) -> ()) {
        self.mask = mask
        self.handler = handler
    }

    deinit {
        stop()
    }

    public func start() {
        monitor = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: mask, handler: handler) as AnyObject?
    }

    public func stop() {
        if monitor != nil {
            NSEvent.removeMonitor(monitor!)
            monitor = nil
        }
    }
}
```

**Tested and works.**